# Why width of view always return zero?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm setting up a view programmatically with all the constraints. Then I want to get its width (which vary from a device to another) but it always return zero when I print it.

here is my code:

```
let myView = UIView()
view.addSubview(myView)
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
myView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -60).isActive = true
myView.backgroundColor = .blue

let myWidth1 = myView.frame.size.width
let myWidth2 = myView.bounds.width
print(myWidth1)
print(myWidth2)
```

however, the view actually has a width as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: When you set up your views in `viewDidLoad()` the actual sizes have not yet been calculated. Try measuring the width in `viewDidAppear()`. By that time everything should be set up.

Comment: Thank you it worked. However, I face the same issue with collectionView where I need to get the width early so I can distribute the cells dynamically depends on the device's width before the appearance of it, any ideas?

Comment: Please post a new question about dynamic cell widths in a `UICollectionView`.

Comment: Or read this: https://medium.com/@NickBabo/equally-spaced-uicollectionview-cells-6e60ce8d457b

Comment: @koen thank you so much for sharing this torurial, I have tried many tutorials in the previous days and none of them worked with me except this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For programmatic development, you should create that view in `loadView()`. `viewDidLoad()` is the lifecycle method that is called after the view has been loaded into memory; however, the view hasn't yet been rendered visually. You can get subview dimensions in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, which will be called throughout view mutations (like device orientation changes) or a method like `viewDidAppear()` that will only be called effectively once.